# "This expression was expected to have type unit" but I want it to be boolean

Tags: types, f#, tuples, unit-type

I'm trying to make a function that compares a tuple with the values of an array of tuples. I need this to return a boolean, but VS2013 keeps telling me:
"This expression was expected to have type 'unit', but has type 'bool'"

```
let compare (i,j,a,(x : (int*int*int) array)) =
    for q in 0 .. x.GetLength(0) do  
        match (i,j,a,x) with
        | (i,j,a,x) when (i,j,a) = x.[q] -> true
        |  _ -> false
```

Also tried to give the values as two parameters, but it doesn't work either:

```
let compare (i,j,a) (x : (int*int*int) array) =
    for q in 0 .. x.GetLength(0) do  
        match (i,j,a) with
        | x.[q] -> true
        |  _ -> false
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand a little bit on the answer from Chris, the main reason why your code does not work is that F# is an *expression-based* language and does not have imperative-style control-flow that you might be expecting here (if you incorrectly read the body of the expression as `return` keyword).

As F# is expression-based, everything is an expression that evaluates to a value. So, `true` is an expression that evaluates to true (boolean). Pattern matching from your example:

```
match (i,j,a,x) with
| (i,j,a,x) when (i,j,a) = x.[q] -> true
|  _ -> false
```

... is also an expression that evaluates to `true` or `false` (boolean value) depending on the values of variables. In this case, conditional would be simpler though:

```
if (i,j,a,x) = x.[q] then true else false
```

... or you could just write the condition `(i,j,a,x) = x.[q]` which means exactly the same thing. Now, `for` loop is tricky, because it evaluates the body multiple times and so it would potentially get multiple return values. For this reason, F# has a special type `unit` (think `void` in C#) which represents a value that does not carry any information. So, `for` loop expects `unit`-returning body like:

```
for i in 1 .. 10 do 
  printfn "Foo"
```

You can check that `printfn "Foo"` actually returns unit value by writing for example:

```
for i in 1 .. 10 do 
  let nothing = printfn "Foo"
  nothing
```

If you place mouse pointer over `nothing`, you'll see that it is of type `unit`.

So, `for` loop is not a good approach if you want to break the iteration in the middle (because it cannot be done in F#). As already mentioned by Chris and Søren you can use functions from the `Array` module to easily implement the logic. Alternatively, you would have to write this using recursion or mutable variables - but the `Array` module works nicely here.

Comment: to expand, "a little" :) - thanks Tomas, I was thinking it was a big jump from the OP's question to the one line implementation, and needed a lot of explaination

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm just learning about F# and its very interesting. Liked you approach!

Answer (score 3):

Short and sweet:

```
let compare triple x = Array.exists ((=) triple) x
```

No need to unpack the tuple `(i, j, x)`.

The notation `(=)`  turns the equality comparison operator into a function of two curried arguments. When we partially apply `(=)` to `triple`, that is, when we write

```
(=) triple
```

we get the function which takes one argument, and compares that argument to `triple`, returning true or false.

Comment: `let compare triple x = Array.exists ((=) triple) x`

Comment: or `let compare triple = Array.exists ((=) triple)`

Comment: Worked smoothly! Thankss!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `for` loop expects the expression within it to evaluate to `unit`. You will need a different approach, for example using `Array.exists`